# how to recover files after (git stash save --include-untrack)

Tags: git, git-stash

How to recover files after (`git stash save --include-untrack`). I used angular 10 and
visual studio Code. I need to recover those files after this command delete it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't put your whole question in bold, this doesn't help in detecting what's important, and it makes your text look as if you were screaming it to others. Also : do take time to evaluate what's useful information and what is not. For example : your question is obviously linked to a git action, so elements like "angular 10" and "visual studio code" are not useful for readers of your question.

Comment: Regarding `git` commands : `git` has an integrated help from the command line : `git help <command>`, and all the doc pages are also published on https://git-scm.com/docs/ . So in your case : running `git help stash` would have led you to [this page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), where `git stash apply` and `git stash pop` are listed. I think that googling for "how do I use git stash" would also have led you to helpful links. This goes towards : before asking on SO, please take time to run a basic search about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it was the last stash, just use `git stash pop`.
If it wasn't, you can find it using `git stash list`

[image]

and then re-apply it with `git stash pop stash@{2}` for example

Comment: its worked but not all the files are back , all main files like app component and approuting and index html the returned without data